# _NT_SYMBOL_PATH adplus windbg issue, not able to set name

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, adplus

In command line I have run the following command: 
C:> set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
[image]

But when I run the following command in adplus.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)>**ADPlus -crash -pn  w3wp
.exe -o C:\dumps**

I always get this warning:
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: you typed that in the same command prompt? If you want to set it permanently you want control panel, system and security, system, advanced system settings, advanced, environment variables - it'll then be set for all programs that you open after you've saved the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the `set` command in a CMD shell it will only set the environment variable for that particular CMD instance and typically child processes.  From your question it looks like you may be running the `set` and `ADPlus` commands from different CMD consoles.  If that's the case this is the source of the problem.

In order to set a permanent environment variable do the following

- Click on the Start Menu
- Right click on Computer and select Properties
- Select Adavanced System Settings
- Click Environment Variables
- Click New on User variables for ...
- Add the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH value there

Answer (score 2):

The variable I'm using is formatted a bit differently (note the "symsrv" instead of just "srv", and the dll is referenced.)  An example can be found on [Microsoft KB 311503](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).

```
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=symsrv*symsrv.dll*d:\debug\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```